# Downscalling chlo-A concentration data of Modis Aqua with Sentinel 2 for Lake Tangayika

Tags: modis, sentinel-2, downscaling

I'm trying to downscale chlo-A data of the Aqua Modis dataset in the region of Lake Tanganyika in order to study the environmental changes in the lake over the past 20 years. I didn't find any code that does this kind of thing.

Can anyone help me with this?